# Add postfix to model name in EF DB FIRST

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I use Entity Framework database first. I would like to append some text to my model class name.
For example

```
Table: Orders => Model: OrderEntity
Table: Products => Model: ProductEntity
Table: Emails => Model: EmailEntity
```

I would like to do this automatic, when I add new table, model class name will have "Entity" postfix.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?